# Experiment: Atwood machine

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

The question is simple: why acceleration obtained during the experiment differs from the one obtained from theory, namely, from the $2d$ Newton's law?

Experiment: 1) we use Atwood machine. 2) employ two different loads, one of which is fixed. Then we use Pasco program which records our results when these loads falling. After the first attempt is taken, we find the inclination of the curve, that is displayed onto the screen, which is the acceleration. Thus, we acquire five values of acceleration ($5$ attempts) $a'$.

Then we know that the problem is of theoretical mechanics and can be solved on the basis of the second Newton's, which yields the answer:

$$a=\frac{(m_1-m_2)g}{m_1+m_2}$$
Where m1 exceed m2, id est 
$m_1 > m_2$
The load $m_2$ never changes, whereas $m_1$ is changed by us.

Question: why $a'$ does not equal to $a$, besides $a'$ does not exceed $a$, it is less than it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observational_error?

Comment: According to your opinion, the difference is justified by measure error. Right? I cannot disagree with that for the reason that, theoretically, the result follows from the 4 fundamental principles, so that the formula is valid. And eventually any device can make mistakes, as well as I could measure something incorrectly, inaccurately but approximately, though I measure no thing, but my computer. Much obliged! This is one of the explanations which are understandable to me.

Comment: In case the answer has been discovered, what should I execute according to the forum rules? Write the answer in "answer your question section"? or delete question?

Comment: Yes, you're encouraged to articulate your own answer if you have already found one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two effects in an actual experiment that your expression ignores:

1. The pulley has some friction; this depends on how the pulley is built, but it may depend on the tension in the rope. Either way, let's just call this force $F$.
2. The pulley has some moment of inertia; let's call that $I = \beta Mr^2$, where $M$ is the mass of the pulley.

With the second effect, $F=ma$ and considering torque gives
$$(m_1+m_2+\beta M)a = (m_1-m_2)g - F\implies a = \frac{(m_1-m_2)g - F}{m_1+m_2+\beta M} $$

Both $F$ and $\beta M$ are positive (if $m_1>m_2$), so this final value will always be less than your ideal value.

Comment: Much obliged! This is enough to complete the explanation and computational process. I have virtually come up with the idea which is that there exist additional forces in the construction, one of which definitely must be friction. But I really thought that the difference is due to the errors made by the program in result of the approximate computational process.